# How to create custom symbols and feed it's chart data from a remote server in real time?

Tags: mql5

I'm trying to learn how to create an MQL5 library for MT5 (I think it should be a library, but not so sure) to create new symbols and feed these symbols chart data from public exchanges APIs in real time.

I tried searching for some tutorial or example of something in these lines, but the best I could found was this [article](https://www.mql5.com/en/articles/3540). Maybe I'm not searching for the correct keywords.

I'm not asking for a complete tutorial or example code to do just that, but maybe some simpler examples so I can have a direction on how to accomplish it.

So, in a nutshell, is there some example codes, tutorials or documentation on how to programmatically create new custom symbols, retrieve chart data from the web, add these data to the custom symbol chart and update it's data in real time (or near real-time)?

Any help in this regard will be much appreciated!

Comment: Did you ever find out how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In MT5 you can now achieve this using Services. You can have your service run in the background and provide custom data to a custom symbol. You can check this article here with an example of feeding a custom symbol from inside a service: [www.mql5.com/en/articles/11826](https://www.mql5.com/en/articles/11826)